# When applicationIdSuffix is appended to applicationId?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I need to change the applicationIdSuffix in a special case and I need to know when exactly it added to applicationId.
[The documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:applicationIdSuffix) doesn't mention when.

I'm using flavors with multiple dimensions.

I tried afterEvaluate and gradle.afterProject tasks but it doesn't contain it and not yet appended to the applicationId.

Answer (score 0):

try this Block in your gradle file

```
android { 
flavorDimensions("company") 
productFlavors {
        example{
            dimension "company"
            applicationIdSuffix ".exampleApp"
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I need when it's value evaluated and added to the applicationId,
I know already how can I do.

Comment: From Build Menu-> select build variant then choose the build variant you want and then build and run your app. the apk will generated with full application id containing applicationIdSuffix

Comment: Please try to understand my question correctly, I need to run a function after the final applicationId combined with the applicationIdSuffix, because I need to rename it in a special flavor cases.

if you have a trial solution it will be great.

Comment: If you specify application Id for example:com.myapp and applicationidsuffix .example app. The generated apk package name will be com.myapp.exampleapp

Comment: yes I know.
but when exactly the android build system doing that?
and could I run a gradle task after it?
I need the rename it before generating the apk with that ID
got it?